# Replacement for Google AJAX search for Local

Tags: api, search, local

Since Google has deprecated their old web search API as of recently, what are people using to do customized local search? (i.e. search for "donut shop" near this latitude and longitude) Sticking with the deprecated API? Using another Google API? Another provider entirely?

Their suggestion to use their new Custom Search API doesn't seem useful for local. Maybe i'm missing something under my nose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Google Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/) is in developer preview.
I personally used [Yahoo! Local Search](http://developer.yahoo.com/search/local/V3/localSearch.html)

Comment: Ah, the Yahoo Local seems like just the thing. Thank you, not sure how I didn't think of looking into that before.

Answer (score 1):

The [Yelp API](http://www.yelp.com/developers) is pretty slick as well -- it'll give you local search capabilities and you can also get ratings information.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this Quora link quite useful:
http://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-alternative-to-Googles-local-search-API